# ng-view is not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have started working in angular js recently. I tried to show the content of the page using ng- view but it shows nothing. It shows content when I put all data in one page i.e., index.html

index.html

```
<html ng-app="customersApp">
    <head>
        <title>
         Iterating over Data         
        </title> 
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
       <link href="animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>

    <div ng-view></div>

        <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
         <script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
         <script src="scripts/angular-animate.js"></script>
         <script src="app/app.js"></script>
        <script src="app/controllers/customersController.js"> </script>



    </body>


</html>
```

app.js:

```
(function(){

var app= angular.module('customersApp',['ngRoute','ngAnimate']);

app.config(function($routeProvider)
{
   $routeProvider 
           .when('/', {

               controller: 'CustomersController',
               templateUrl: 'customers.html'
           })

           otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

   }); 




}());
```

customersController.js:

```
(function(){
    var CustomersController = function ($scope){
    $scope.sortBy = 'name';
    $scope.reverse = 'false';
    $scope.customers= [{joined:'2000-12-02',name:'Prince',city:'sitamarhi',ordertotal:9.9956},{joined:'2000-12-03',name:'Pinku',city:'kendrapara',ordertotal:9.9856},{joined:'2000-12-04',name:'Amit',city:'sambalpur',ordertotal:9.9756}];
    $scope.doSort = function(propName){
    $scope.sortBy = propName;
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;                  
              };
          };

    CustomersController.$inject = ['$scope'];
angular.module('customersApp')
        .controller('CustomersController', CustomersController);
   }());
```

I am not getting where I am making a mistake.

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: yes errors are: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module customersApp due to:
ReferenceError: otherwise is not defined

Comment: you missed `.` before otherwise

Comment: you missed `.` before `overwise`

Comment: There is a . missing

Comment: it still shows one error:  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

missing `.` before otherwise in $routeProvider

Comment: it still shows one error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Then you are missing some resource, can you check in your dev-tool

Comment: sorry its my first question. It needs 15 reputation to accept